# adding object to list of objects

Tags: c#

I'm getting an exception and I'm not seeing what I'm missing.

I have an object model called MyComposedModel and I'm creating a list of these by adding each element as they're built.

I have this:

```
List<MyComposedModel> TheListOfModel = null;
MyComposedModel ThisObject = new MyComposedModel();

foreach (MyComposedModel in some list)
{
 ThisObject.Reset() //clears all properties
 ....
 TheListOfModel.Add(ThisObject)
}
```

And I'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the Add(ThisObject) line.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Not related to the error you're seeing, but you are adding the same object over and over to your list.  Each ThisObject.Reset() will clear the object you have added to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to initialize `TheListOfModel` first. Instead of:

```
List<MyComposedModel> TheListOfModel = null;
```

do this:

```
List<MyComposedModel> TheListOfModel = new List<MyComposedModel> ();
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Just to know: I have an object and one of the properties of the object is a list called ThisList. In the Reset method, I have ThisList = null; Is this the correct way of clearing the list or is it going to bug there too?

Comment: ThisList.Clear() will remove all the elements.

Comment: Yes, I would use ThisList.Clear(). It is more declarative. (Readers of your code know exactly what you are doing)

Comment: So I guess you should never initialize a list with List<Objects> MyList = null; but instead should use List<Objects> MyList = new List<Objects>(); Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TheListOfModel is null, so you can't apply a method on it.